# Specify header and footer to appear on every page when printed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to specify text to appear on the bottom and header of every page when printed?

or

Is there a CSS solution which would allow a header and footer to repeat on each printed page?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is a bit too general, I'm assuming you want that specific text to appear only on your print page and not in your website. Just do a

```
<p class="print-this">TEXT TO BE SHOWN IN PRINT</p>
```

then in your print.css

```
.print-this {
  display: block;
}
```

and in your main.css

```
.print-this {
  display: none;
}
```

Oh and you need to include your stylesheet with the media option as Giu said:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: you should also mention that both `link` elements for including the CSS files should define the appropriate value for the `media` attribute, i.e. for print: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />` and for the screen: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />`

Comment: thanks for ur answer , but what i meant was like a header and footer we include in a word document so it prints on every page we print.Hope it makes some sense

Comment: @Giu, oh yeah sorry i'll add that up. @manraj, yup, you include that html code in every page you have(if you're using a layout like in rails, that's easy since you just need to change one file)

Comment: no what i meant was Is there a CSS solution which would allow a header and footer to repeat on each printed page?

Answer (score 1):

Using position:fixed, should render on every page when used in a print context

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Headers

Comment: This is the solution that should work, according to the spec, although not all browsers conform.