# Specify which parts of the HTML page should be saved/printed

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to specify which parts of an HTML page should be saved and printed, in cases where the page consists of Flash elements and other things that you do not want saved/printed.

The `<style>` element in the page head allows you to specify CSS styles for display and printing separately, but I'm looking for a way to filter HTML elements for display/saving/printing.

Comment: You could use media queries to set `display: none` on things you don't want to print, perhaps?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625755/is-there-a-way-to-specify-text-to-appear-on-the-bottom-and-header-of-every-page -- what about saving? would that also follow the rules for the "print" CSS stylesheet?

Comment: I don't know about saving, which is why I let a comment and not an answer. Yes, that SO question is similar to what I suggested, but you could also use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: By save I mean when the user saves the page using the browser's standard File > Save system... or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to accomplish this is by using a media query. See the codepen: https://codepen.io/eTech77/pen/dyjbRVM

HTML

```
<p id="no-show">and this won't</p>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
#no-show {
display: none;
}
}
```

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm for more information. Hope this helps!